# Turn string into multidimensional array

Tags: java, string, multidimensional-array

I have a string:

```
String stringProfile = "0, 4.28 10, 4.93 20, 3.75";
```

I am trying to turn it into an array like as follows:

```
double [][] values = {{FastMath.toRadians(0), FastMath.toRadians(4.28)},
                      {FastMath.toRadians(10), FastMath.toRadians(4.93)},
                      {FastMath.toRadians(20), FastMath.toRadians(3.75)}};
```

Where `FastMath.toRadians` is a method on each element.

Number of issues:

First logical thing to do is to split the string:

```
List<String> stringProfileList= Arrays.asList(stringProfile.split(" "));
```

The output would be `"0, 4.28, 10, 4.93, 20, 3.75"`, so now every element is split by a "," rather than every other.

Then for every 2 elements in the list, I need to assign to an array. 
Within each Array I apply the FastMath.toRadians() on each element and then I append each array to a larger multidimensional array.

Is this the right way to go about this? I'm getting stuck at implementing for every 2 elements.

I also need to convert these string elements into a double, which doesn't seem to trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `Stream` try this:

```
    Pattern PAIR = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\d)\\s(?=\\d)");

    double[][] result = PAIR.splitAsStream(stringProfile)
            .map(pair -> pair.split(","))
            .map(pair -> new double[] { FastMath.toRadians(Double.valueOf(pair[0])), FastMath.toRadians(Double.valueOf(pair[1])) })
            .toArray(i -> new double[i][]);
```

A `Pattern` is used to split `stringProfile` on whitespace characters which have a digit *behind* and *ahead* them. This results in a `Stream` of strings which contains a pair of numbers divided by `', '`. We `split` this string on `','` in a first `map` to get an array of strings representing the numbers. In the next `map` the numbers a parsed and their radians is computed.

We could devide the parsing of the numbers and the comuputation of the radians to single `map` steps. The following code is more verbose but creates an additional double array:

```
double[][] result = PAIR.splitAsStream(stringProfile)
        .map(pair -> pair.split(","))
        .map(pair -> new double[] { Double.valueOf(pair[0]), Double.valueOf(pair[1]) })
        .map(pair -> new double[] { FastMath.toRadians(pair[0]), FastMath.toRadians(pair[1]) })
        .toArray(i -> new double[i][]);
```

If we want to reuse the double array, we can do this like this:

```
        .map(pair -> {
            pair[0] = FastMath.toRadians(pair[0]);
            pair[1] = FastMath.toRadians(pair[1]);
            return pair;
        })
```

The last step collects the double arrays into a two dimensional array.

---

EDIT:

Have a look on [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/7QcBEv/1).

Using the wording of the documentation of the [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class the used pattern looks for a *whitespace* character (`\\s`) which is preceded (`(?<=\\d)` = *look behind*) and succeeded (`(?=\\d)` = *look ahead*) by one digit (`\\d`). These *looks* have *zero-width*, thus they are evaluated for capturing (matching) but are not part of the *matched sequence* ([`Matcher.group()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group())). The *matching sequence* contains only a *whitespace* character (`\\s`).

For `stringProfile` this pattern will match in two cases: `"8 1"` and `"3 2"`. In these cases two digits are surrounding a `" "`. On the other hand e.g. `"0, 4"` doesn't match. The occurrence of `","` prevents a match.

Comment: pity u deleted that answer though, was working on some suggestions... since you deleted it, [I added it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52329337/1059372) don't rush next time

Comment: @Eugene Don't worry. I wasn't convinced myself after reading the specification. Maybe I'll come up with a better solution.

Comment: I really like this solution. I'd confused by the syntax of the regex. Could you break that down how it works? Cheers

Comment: @arsenal88 I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, appreciated. I'm confused by the \\d notation. As this should take any digit, but it doesnt recognise negatives. I cant find notation for optional negatives on digits.

Comment: @arsenal88 A digit is one chararcter from the class `[0-9]` (see Pattern JavaDoc), it has no sign. To handle _negative numbers_ you can use this pattern: `"(?<=\\d)\\s-?(?=\\d)"`. The minus sign may only occour in front of the second digit of the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, first split the string to a list of substrings, then do a foreach over the list and add your FastMath torad result to a new resultlist:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Double> results = new ArrayList<Double>();
for (String string : list) {
   results.add(FastMath.toRadians(Double.valueOf(string)));
}
results.toArray();
```

the next thing you do is split the array to a new multi dimensional array of your choice, by iterating over it and sorting it into your multidimensional array.

However If you're not forced to use arrays I'd use a higher datataype like maps or lists, or a tuple or something better suiting your needs. Just check out what java collections offers you.

Answer (score 0):

If you split on a space **not** preceded by a comma you get comma-separated pairs. These can then be split again and mapped into `Double[]`.

You can add any further processing afterwards.

```
private void test() {
    String s = "0, 4.28 10, 4.93 20, 3.75";
    // Split on space without comma beforehand.
    Double[][] doubles = Arrays.stream(s.split("(?<!,) "))
            // Then split each pair.
            .map(pairString -> pairString.split(", "))
            // Make each pair into a Double[]
            .map(pair -> new Double[]{Double.valueOf(pair[0]), Double.valueOf(pair[1])})
            // to array of Double[][]
            .toArray(Double[][]::new);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(doubles));
}
```

> [[0.0, 4.28], [10.0, 4.93], [20.0, 3.75]]